# iMac doesn't boot from same usb that works on MacBook Air

Tags: boot, usb, mac

I have created a bootable USB with Ubuntu that works fine on my MacBook Air (year 2011) but is not detected by my iMac (2004) when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>. rEFIx does not help either. 
I have tried with other distros (although it is also based on Ubuntu) and get the same result. 
Isn't this strange? 
Thanks.
Esteban

Comment: What is "MBA"??

Answer (score 0):

Your iMac probably has a PowerPC processor -- making it's incompatible with the x86/64 build that you'd be using on your Mac Book Air (I assume that's what MBA means). Apple didn't even start using Intel processors until about 2006. Therefore, in order to install it on an iMac you'd have to find a PowerPC build of Ubuntu.

Have a look at the [PowerPC FAQ on the Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PowerPCFAQ). Looks like the only option for PowerPC currently is Lubuntu. The PowerPC ISO can be found [here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/trusty/release/lubuntu-14.04-desktop-powerpc.iso).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies. That is the most weird because my iMac is an intel core 2 duo, 2.0GHz. MBA is Macbook Air. The problem is that my superdrive is faulty, so installing ubuntu via usb is the only way for me unless I buy an external unit.

Comment: Oh, that's weird. From what I read, all iMacs had PowerPC. When i think "iMac" I think the fat OS 9 desktops I had in middle school, apparently they still make them o.O! Then, it may be an EFI issue. Let me look into it further and I will post a new answer (getting Mac-specific EFI -- especially the older ones -- is a pain from what I've read before).

Comment: Can you provide me with your Mac's model number? I believe it might be a late 2006 model from what I've read, but just to be sure....

Comment: Hi, I'm now between houses and the imac is in the box already packed, but it could be a 2006 model, although I believe it is one year older. It is one of those first iMacs with intel inside, just after the G5 with PPC. It came with Tiger.

Comment: I have been researching and it is a late 2006 iMac. MA590LL/A

Comment: OK, that's what I figured. So, it uses a 32-bit EFI which may be the problem. How did you create the USB? Did you use `dd` or a tool like unetbootin?

Comment: Also, since the EFI is 32-bit this limits it to only 32-bit operating systems as well. If the version of Ubuntu on your flash drive is 64-bit it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Older Macs cannot boot BIOS based OS's via USB, afaik, Only macs that don't come with a DVD/CD drive can boot non efi OS's on USBs. (Such as MBAs)

Comment: Hi Brandon. I didn't know that. I thought it would be ok with rEFIx, but your answer really helps. I have a question that could be stupid: if I buy an external dvd drive, is it going to boot even if I need to connect it via usb or is it going to behave like a pen drive? Thanks.

Comment: Answering myself: yes, it is possible. I am running now elementary os.